# Requests.post is taking lot of time and cpu

Tags: python, python-requests, spnego, python-requests-html

I did a `post` request to get the specified field, but it is taking a long time.

```py
for i in list:
    Data={queryValue:i[columnA]}    
    Response=requests.post(url,auth=HTTPSPNEGO(),json=data)
    ColumnB=Response.json()[datalist][account]
```

This is taking 2-4 hours to run and 10-20 G of CPU. Can this be reduced?

Comment: please fix the code formatting

Comment: How long does each POST take?